# Try to make Discord calculator but it's not working

Tags: python, discord, calculator

I want make a Discord calculator but, when i try to bring a,b1,b2,b3,c
from discord app with {!calculator 1774,117,34,22,0} in this format
but error happend

```
discord.ext.commands.errors.MissingRequiredArgument: b1 is a required argument that is missing.
```

How can I make it work...?

this is the code I script

```
#calculator def
def cal(a,b1,b2,b3,c):
  b = b1+b2+b3
  if c == 1 :
    f = a/1.1 - b
  else :
    f = a-b
  print(f'result is {f}!')

# !calculator
@bot.command()
async def calculator(ctx,a,b1,b2,b3,c):
  await ctx.send('Start calculate.')
  await ctx.send(cal(a,b1,b2,b3,c))
```

Answer (score 0):

Arguments that are passed into discord.py bot commands need to be separated by a space. Try testing it with `!calculator 1774 117 34 22 0` instead.

Comment: I test with `!calculator 1774 117 34 22 0` but it brings another error

this time it shows me 

`discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: unsupported operand type(s) for -: 'str' and 'str'`

Comment: Patryk Szczepański's answer is correct, you need to cast the arguments to floats to do arithmetic with them

Answer (score 0):

Your code is correct, but you need to pass variables as floats. You could also use args/kwargs logic to pass variables instead of doing bunch of casts.

```py
# calculator def
def cal(a, b1, b2, b3, c):
    b = b1+b2+b3
    if c == 1.0:
        f = a/1.1 - b
    else:
        f = a - b
    print(f'result is {f}!')

# !calculator
@bot.command()
async def calculator(ctx, a, b1, b2, b3, c):
    await ctx.send('Start calculate.')
    await ctx.send(
        cal(float(a), float(b1), float(b2), float(b3), float(c)))
```